# Unique constraint (%s.%s) violated - Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database.

I am trying to update a record in a table using "Update ... Where ..." statement.

Even though I get only a one record when I execute a "Select * from ... where...." condition and using the same "Where" condition I am executing "Update" statement. I am getting below error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (<Unique Constraint Name>) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

What I am not getting is when there is a single record which I get using "Where" condition and updating is affecting a single record, then what is the reason I am getting above error.

Comment: Please show your full UPDATE statement, the SELECT you're using to find only one record, and all the of constraints that exist on your table.

Comment: If you're only (trying to) update one record, than another record *already* has the values you're setting for that row. The constraint is comparing the row you're changing with all the other rows in the table - it is not only looking at the rows you're actually touching in this statement.

Comment: @Alex: I even tried to execute the select statement by putting the update statement column value, but didn't get any record.

Comment: @VishalTiwari - I'm not sure what that means. Please add the information MatBaile asked for to the question, along with whatever you executed that got no data. Also include the table structure so we can see the column data types. And check if there are any triggers, just in case.

Comment: Add your statement and constraints here. Probably your new values violating one of them.

Comment: Let me see, coz there are some other tables involved as FK.